# how to cancel build queue jobs in jenkins, which are not started by jenkins and are in its build queue through REST API

Tags: api, rest, jenkins, hudson-api

how to cancel build queue jobs in jenkins through REST API, which are not started by jenkins and are in its build queue. I know how to cancel the in-progress job with below command

```
curl -X POST <jenkins-server>/job/<job-name>/<build-number>/doDelete
```

Answer (score 7):

To cancel a job in the queue, you can POST:

```
http://jenkins/queue/cancelItem?id=x
```

To find x, you can parse the result of:

```
http://jenkins/queue/api/json?tree=items[id,task[name]]
```

To cancel a build that is in progress:

```
http://jenkins/job/<jobName>/y/stop
```

To find y, you can parse the result of:

```
http://jenkins/job/<jobName>/lastBuild/api/json?tree=building,number
```

Comment: thanks allan, but as I am automating this from front-end its becoming quite difficult to delete or cancel particular job with only ID. Can we stop jenkins from making build queue ?

Answer (score 2):

It's not possible to cancel a job by its build number, only through the job id:

```
curl -X POST 'http://jenkins/queue/cancelItem?id=85'
```

Comment: No its not working, i tried  curl -X POST http://<jenkins-server>/queue/cancelItem?id=152 , curl --data '' http://<jenkins-server/queue/cancelItem?id=154 and whenever i am posting this link http://<jenkins-server/queue/cancelItem?id=154 output is  -POST is required for hudson.model.Queue.doCancelItem, so can't we do something with doCancelItem which I did similarly with doDelete?

Comment: Well, --data '' is used for sending a POST request with curl.

Comment: Try curl  --request POST 'http://jenkins/queue/cancelItem?id=154' or curl -X POST '.....id=154'

Comment: No its not working, curl --request POST <jenkins>/queue/cancelItem?id=167

Comment: Hi Eduardo, sorry this one worked but only with id, I am trying to do this with build number

Comment: try with build=XXX instead of id=XXX

Comment: also i think it will be more feasible to find a way to do cancelitem like this - :  curl -X POST <jenkins-server>/job/<job-name/164/doDelete...as I am automating this from a website, cause particular job name and its build number becomes systematic

Comment: Both are not working..it seems jenkins only taking id,                               curl --request POST <jenkins>/queue/cancelItem?build=167 or curl --request POST <jenkins>/queue/cancelItem?nextBuildNumber=167